# Query on if block helper and custom helper in handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I was unable to execute the below code on the handlebars template. Can you please point out the error in the below code?

```
{{#if (isGreen PARAM1 PARAM2)}}
          <td scope="col">GREEN</td>
{{/if}}
```

Where `isGreen` is custom register helper as shown below :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isGreen', function (PARAM1, PARAM2) 
{
 //SOME STEPS
 return true;
}
```

My intention of the above is to print the content within the `if` block if only the registerHelper returns `true`.

I am getting the below error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includeZero' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something you can't chain helpers : you can't call a helper in another one. #if is a helper and isGreen is another one.

What you can do is to put the #if logic in your custom helper.

Your html will look like this :

```
{{#isGreen PARAM1 PARAM2)}}
          <td scope="col">GREEN</td>
{{/isGreen}}
```

and your script is like this :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isGreen', function (PARAM1, PARAM2, options) {
    // Some steps where you'll set the doDisplay variable 
    // accordingly with your logic
    if (doDisplay) {
        // Your condition is met display something
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        // Your condition isn't met display nothing
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you